# What is the equivalent of Django's DecimalField in Java?

Tags: java, android, python, django

I have an Android app which communicates with a Django backend. I am currently using DecimalField to represent money related variables, like:

```
from django.db import models
...
fee = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=3)
```

Is there an equivalent data type in Java I can use, or should I store the number in two parts(decimal part and fraction part separately)?

Comment: I think you're probably looking for `BigDecimal`. Note that if you're sending it as JSON, you'll need to use a string instead of a number.

Comment: @chrylis, yes I am sending data as JSON, like "10.90". I think BigDecimal is what I needed, thank you for fast response. Can you write answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard Java class for arbitrary-precision decimal numbers is `BigDecimal`. Note that if you're sending as JSON, you'll need to use a string instead of a number (all JSON numbers are floating-point), and your database setup may need special care to save the numbers like you want.